# Optimising the query which has joins and unions in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, optimization, union

I am using the laravel to build my web app. In that for listing all orders I have an query but it takes upto 40s in my localhost whereas in goddady shared hosting it takes upto 95s. Although I implemented the server side datatable yet the query takes bit long to execute. I need someone to suggest or help to make the query to excute more efficient. There are majorly two sets and I make that union.

```
select * from ((
select `subscription`.`id`, 
`subscription`.`order_id`, 
`users`.`name` as `user_name`, 
`subscription`.`new_dated`,
`subscription`.`rescheduling_delivery_date` as expected_date, 
COUNT(`subscription_items`.`product_id`) as items, 
`subscription`.`od_dis_total` as `total`,
`subscription`.`order_discount`, 
`area`.`area_name`,
`subscribe_orders`.`action` as ordertype,
driver.name as driver_name,
'NA' as payment_mode, 
`payment_status`.`status_name` as payment_status,
`subscription_status`.`status_name` as order_status, 
`subscription`.`od_payment_method`,
`subscription_items`.`product_id`, 
subscription.delivered_dated
from `subscription` 
left join `subscription_items` on `subscription`.`id` = `subscription_items`.`subscription_id` 
left join `users` on `subscription`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` 
left join `users` as `driver` on `subscription`.`driver_id` = `driver`.`id` 
left join `ycias_address` on `subscription`.`add_id` = `ycias_address`.`id` 
left join `area` on `ycias_address`.`area_id` = `area`.`id` 
left join `subscribe_order_items` on `subscription`.`subscribe_order_id` = `subscribe_order_items`.`subscribe_order_id` 
left join `subscribe_orders` on `subscription`.`subscribe_order_id` = `subscribe_orders`.`id` 
left join `payment_status` on `subscription`.`payment_status` = `payment_status`.`id` 
left join `subscription_status` on `subscription`.`od_status` = `subscription_status`.`id` 
group by `subscription_items`.`subscription_id`) 
union (
select `orders`.`id`, 
`orders`.`order_id`, 
`users`.`name` as `user_name`, 
`orders`.`new_dated`,
`orders`.`expected_delivery_date` as expected_date, 
COUNT(order_items.product_id) as items,
`orders`.`od_dis_total` as `total`, 
`orders`.`order_discount`, 
`area`.`area_name`, 
'Instant Order' as ordertype, 
driver.name as driver_name, 
orders.payment_mode, 
`payment_status`.`status_name` as payment_status, 
`order_status`.`status_name` as order_status, 
`orders`.`od_payment_method`,
`order_items`.`product_id`, 
`orders`.`delivered_dated` 
from `orders` 
left join `order_items` on `orders`.`id` = `order_items`.`order_id` 
left join `users` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` 
left join `users` as `driver` on `driver`.`id` = `orders`.`driver_id` 
left join `ycias_address` on `orders`.`add_id` = `ycias_address`.`id` 
left join `area` on `ycias_address`.`area_id` = `area`.`id` 
left join `payment_status` on `orders`.`payment_status` = `payment_status`.`id` 
left join `order_status` on `orders`.`od_status` = `order_status`.`id` 
group by `order_items`.`order_id`)) as all_orders limit 10 offset 0
```

Comment: Start with something (much) simpler. Whatever optimisations we can suggest for that will surely apply to your eventual query (which hopefully will be unrecognisable from the travesty provided above)

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions**, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: @Strawberry I edited the query as simpler, can you please suggest

Comment: @AndyLester Added index and seen improvement. That now I got executed at 19s

Comment: @AndyLester Can you please tell me how row count will affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the suggestion given by [Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester) I have added the **index** for the necessary columns. So the execution time is reduced to half that is **18 secs** in localhost. I further investigated that the index columns are of datatype **VARCHAR**. So I changed that to **INT** and then executed, got results within **0.9 secs**. Thanks to [Andy Lester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8454/andy-lester).